# Blank page after adding JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am getting a white page after adding jquery to my master page:

```
<!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="/_catalogs/masterpage/mymp/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" ID="jquery" Localizable="False" LoadAfterUI="True"  OnDemand="true" runat="server" >-->
<!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
```

What could be wrong?

The rendered page returns this:

```
<html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="Robots" content="NOINDEX " /></head><body></body>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                 var gearPage = document.getElementById('GearPage');
                 if(null != gearPage)
                 {
                     gearPage.parentNode.removeChild(gearPage);
                     document.title = "Errore";
                 }
                 </script>
                 </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably getting this error because SharePoint does not find the file!

Double check the path to the jQuery.js file and that the file is published. Or, use a normal `<script>` tag to get around the problem with the whole page blowing up when the file is not found.

Comment: I've used the normal tag script.thnaks

Comment: excuse me but can anyone elaborate on the comment 'use a normal <script> tag'? I have the same problem but unfortunately I don't get the answer...
tnx!

Comment: I used this:<script language="javascript" src="/Style Library/scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

**Scriptlink** works as well, just remove **OnDemand="true"** which requires calls to SP.SOD.execute or SP.SOD.executeFunc methods for any JS script referenced to execute.

Detailed explanation has been posted here before: [jQuery not being loaded from master page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/129404/jquery-not-being-loaded-from-master-page/129407#129407)

The above works provided if your jquery reference path is correct!

Answer (score 0):

My two cents on this subject...

I got the same issue when referencing a JS file in `_catalogs` folder with ScriptLink. I traced it to the starting '~' key.

In my case this worked (notice the **~sitecollection/** part):

```
name="~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/mymp/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"
```