# SP 2013 Central Administration White Screen of Death

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, central-administration

I have an on-premises installation of SharePoint 2013 on a development server, with a dedicated SQL Server instance on another server. Recently, my Central Administration site would stop loading and show a simple white screen.

Looking at the page source that comes back, I get the following:

```
<html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="Robots" content="NOINDEX " /></head><body></body>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                 var gearPage = document.getElementById('GearPage');
                 if(null != gearPage)
                 {
                     gearPage.parentNode.removeChild(gearPage);
                     document.title = "Error";
                 }
                 </script>
                 </html>
```

I do not see any errors in the ULS or in the server event logs.

I have restarted both IIS and the SharePoint server. I have also successfully re-provisioned the Central Administration instance by using the following commands:

Unprovision: `psconfig.exe -cmd adminvs unprovision`

Provision: `New-SPCentralAdministration -Port <your-port-num>`

This [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159958/central-administration-page-is-blank) suggests that SharePoint be completely re-installed, but that's not an acceptable solution for me. Does anyone have any suggestions for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I would do following things to troubleshoot the issue.

- [Enable the IIS](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-central-admin-http-error-enable-failed-request-trace-logging/) trace logging to get the actual error.
- [Turn Off the Custom Logging](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Roji.Joy/disable-custom-error-mode-in-sharepoint-2010/) for the Central admin site.
- Check the ULS logs and Event Logs for more clue.
- Make Sure Default Web Site is stoped
- Make Sure the Central admin App Pool and SharePoint timer service are running under the Farm admin account.
- try to disable the loop back check on the server.
- Run this command `Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration` see if it return the Central admin. if Yes then try to use the url mentioned in it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggetions. I was always getting an HTTP 200 response when loading the site. It just woudn't return any content. Howerver, changing the web.config to `debug="false"` allows the site to load, albeit very slow. I'll keep digging, but thanks for your help!

Comment: most useful is turning off Custom Logging... immediately revealed the error. Don't forget to reverse the web.config settings